# My voicemail is gone

Tags: samsung, sim-card, voicemail

My carrier is consumer Cellular they sent me a new SIM card because they said mine needed to be updated. After inserting the new one my voicemail is gone. I tried to set it up again but it says my phone number is not associated with the voicemail on my phone. Everything else is working so I’m assuming I put the new SIM card in correct. I have a Samsung Galaxy A21.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the carrier?  Maybe they dont support free voicemail anymore.

Comment: So far the carrier hasn’t been much help. I’m going to try them again. Maybe I need to switch carriers.

Comment: After I got through to my carrier they tried to fix it. Now my phone won’t work at all. I’m going to have to try a factory reset.